# Showing that $x^2-t$ is an irreducible polynomial in $Z_2(t)[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show that the polynomial $f(x)=x^2-t$ is irreducible in $Z_2(t)[x]$, where $Z_2(t)$ is the quotient field of $Z_2[t]$. Here is my attempt:

So, if $f$ has a root, and $\alpha$ is that root, of course $\alpha^2=t$. But since $\alpha\in Z_2(t)$ then there are $p(t),q(t)\in Z_2[t]$ such that $\alpha=\dfrac{p(t)}{q(t)}$. So $\dfrac{p(t)^2}{q(t)^2}=t$. But i can't find a good way to finish the result by this equation. Any hint?

Comment: What is $Z_2$? Did you mean the field of 2 elements $\mathbb{Z}_2$ or $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: The first one that you writte. Sorry, i don't know how is the command to write in this form

Comment: Is that $1$ supposed to be a $t$?

Comment: Yes! Sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Multiply both sides by $q(t)^2$; you're left with the polynomial equation $p(t)^2 = q(t)^2 t$. Now compare degrees.

Comment: So $2deg(p(t))=2deg(q(t))+1$, a contradiction!! It's correct isn't?

Comment: Indeed; $p(t)^2$ has an even degree and $q(t)^2 t$ odd.